# How to default generic function arguments with intersection types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out why the following code will not work as I expect it to. The intersection type seems to work fine (when redefined inside of the function) however using it as the default to a generic argument type does not.

```js
interface A {
    a: string
}

interface B {
    b: string
}

interface C {
    c: string
}

function returnStuff<T = A & B>(
    optionalReturnFn?: (value: T) => T): (value: T) => T {
    const defaultReturnFn = (value: T) => {
        value.a // <----- why does this a error
        return value
    }
        return optionalReturnFn ? optionalReturnFn : defaultReturnFn
}

function returnStuff2<T extends A & B>(
    optionalReturnFn?: (value: T) => T): (value: T) => T {
    const defaultReturnFn = (value: T) => {
        value.a // <----- while this one does not
        return value
    }
        return optionalReturnFn ? optionalReturnFn : defaultReturnFn
}

const bc: B & C = { b: 'b', c: 'c' } // <--- valid intersection type

// Works as expected when calling fn but DOESN't work as I'd expect internally to fn
returnStuff<B & C>((value) => { 
    return value
 })

// Doesn't work when calling fn but DOES work as expected internally to fn
returnStuff2<B & C>((value) => { 
    return value
 })
```

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKAQprgcgEYnmUQNHPRyNw0eEmQBhTngIJ+FanQY4YAVxAIwwAPYhkUCGE1QQAZTMwYAHgAqyALxpkAMmRsAfAAouBPoADnqGcAA2AEqm5iAAYiAA-CS+AG4RmhAkDgCULt7IuSnp4ZnZec4FTtgK+AiG5MgAJhDwmuFg0WYWCS7IaRlZhRUFNdzcJZkAdHDIAPRzyHYAtKuryADuABYAns36EKTIYFvAR7PQUPpQAePGMRbIkxC3yKJ3+CbdRsGhIBFdWK9RLIX4Gf5RB7xIwkFptDqAnogNRiDTaXTg+7fayaWwAJkcyAgAA9ICAmkd0J4fP5aqCQuCAVCEsl+s9yvlhsVBhzKoV5Nx6iBGnC4O1OsyjK4BqUhrlOWMPs8ZvNFis1stNqdwigTmdQSAUE0DkcQPowK9uF9Yk9Bq93h9rY8wWFId9gfS-kz3TDmq0xQjJSjcELGjwlF4PLI+hheCQAOQ8eMAGmQEfjCHjb3UC2QAHVrgBrc5HElBCC6CBNLUQIwICLhajIGBGHiaMDIAAiAHkAKKWABy8Y7GyLhCOAEl49WyxWO0xoBDwnswPpm8icE6rDZ7BxPDI-DLMiNMMhXlvbbKuLQcjnFp2TSBh5sx9ta2mG02W7x212+5YXygQtxyJYly0rasFwsBsVzXFtcC3HF8TsPdZEPZ4T1jc8oUvTJrxyIA) if you'd like to play around with the errors.

**UPDATE**: I ended up adding a type guard and using it in the `returnStuff` function definition.

```js
...
function isDefaultType<DefaultType>(
    record: any,
    keys: string[]
): record is DefaultType {
    return every(keys, (key) => key in record)
}

function returnStuff<T = A & B>(
    optionalReturnFn?: (value: T) => T): (value: T) => T {
    const defaultReturnFn = (value: T) => {
        if(isDefaultType<T>(value, ['a', 'b']) {
            value.a // <----- no longer throws an error
            return value
        }
    }
        return optionalReturnFn ? optionalReturnFn : defaultReturnFn
}
```

Comment: `value.a` errors in the default case because default `returnStuff` could be called without the default type parameter.  There's nothing enforcing them being used together. it works in the extended case because the generic is constrained to have the `a` property

Comment: @bryan60 Got it. in that case would I have to have a type guard inside `returnStuff`'s `defaultReturnFn` to check whether it was defaulted to `A & B`? Also, doesn't that defeat the purpose of a default? I'm looking for a clean way to say "if a generic isn't passed it's safe to assume `T`  is `A & B`

Comment: yes, you would need some type guard to ensure the type parameter passed is in fact the default type. I wouldn't say it defeats the purpose of default types, because this is a non typical use case for a default. A default type is doing exactly what you say, but the piece you're missing is that the use of the default function is NOT linked to the use of the default type. they exist and are invoked independently. And as far as I know, in ts, there isn't a way to require that default parameters be used or not used together.

Answer (score 3):

**returnStuff**

`T = A & B` shows the error beside `value.a` because you've only set a default value, but you didn't limit types of `T` via `extends`, `T` can still be anything, but if it wasn't specified it would be `A & B`.
`returnStuff<C>(v => v);` - works. `returnStuff(v => v);` - works too. `value.a` fails because `value` can be anything, string, undefined etc.

the right way would be `T extends A & B = A & B`

**returnStuff2**

`returnStuff2<B & C>` doesn't work because `T extends A & B` (not a default value, but a defined base type) requires `a` property which is missed in union of `B` and `C`.

Comment: hmm `T extends A & B = A & B` does not seem to work like I initially thought. It basically just accomplishes the same as `returnStuff2` with the `extends` and doesn't allow `<B & C>` to be passed as a generic. I guess my question still remains... is there a way to default a generic type passed to a function definition so that 

1. Accessors within the fn definition are type safe
2. The generic type can be overridden when the fn is called

I assume it would have to use some combination of `extends` and `=`.

Comment: `A & B` will never allow `B & C`, because `B & C` misses `A`. Why do you want to pass `B & C` into `A & B`? And why do you want to keep it as `A & B` when you aren't passing `A` there? Maybe you need to specify just `B` instead of `A & B`.

Comment: `A&B` is like to say - we accept `credit cards` and to pass there `B&C` is like to say - I want to pay with `cash`, it is still money (`B`), but it's not a `credit card`.